# How to fully remove subversive plugin

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, subversive, eclipse-indigo

I've installed Subversive and want to switch to the Subclipse plugin.

After uninstalling Subversive via About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Uninstall... and installing Subclipse, there are now two SVN options available in Preferences -> Team, one for Subversive preferences (which has been uninstalled and shouldn't be there anymore), and one for Sublipse preferences.

How to remove Subversive completely, so that there aren't any traces (such as Subversive's preferences screen) left in Eclipse?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Remove from Eclipse's plugins and features folders all files and folders like:

```
org.eclipse.team.svn*
org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn*
```

Comment: Do this in your eclipse root directory (e.g., C:\eclipse). I was looking for the plugins in the .metadata folder in my workspace before I realized this.

Comment: I searched "svn" in STS (eclipse derived) folder. they were present in plugins, features, and configurations folder. But even after deleting all of the jars and folders which contains "svn" in it, the issue isn't resolved.

Answer (score 22):

Help->about eclipse->installation details->Installed Software tab
You can choose the software to uninstall.

Comment: This does not work - that's why the question was asked in the first place.

Comment: This apparently worked for me, but I still see several folders referring to Polarion and svn (see Markus answer).  Uninstalling from Marketplace doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

If you have installed Subversive via Eclipse Marketplace:

From Eclipse menu open Help -> Eclipse Market Place...

Then search for subversive, click uninstall under **Subversive - SVN Team Provider**

Restart the Eclipse.

Comment: This looked like it helps but actually it doesn't remove anything