# Error "Failed to load java HL library" on importing svn project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

When I try to checkout [my project](https://xp-dev.com/svn/spaceworld) in Eclipse in doesn't work. What can I do about it? It just waits and nothing happens.

[image]

So I wasted my time completely and instead I can install the subclipse plugin, and right away nothing is possible again:

[image]

Comment: Check this out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769989/failed-to-load-javahl-library

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659587/failed-to-load-javahl-library-linux-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you receive your svn repository via svn on the commandline? You should try to get it there and then import it to eclipse via `File->Import...`. That also adds the usual SVN capabilities to the eclipse project if the svn plugin is installed correctly.

What svn plugin are you using? There are subversive and subclipse, and I had different experiences using either of them.

Could you fetch any other svn repository via the dialog? Just get one on github(click Subversion right there where you get the git url) and try to get it.

Comment: Yes I can receive my repo on the commandline. I don't understand how to import it because it is not only "import...", it must be some more choice. And no, I can't fetch any other svn repo because eclipse is not working. I'm using subversive and I couldn't find subclipse and I can't understand how to uninstall the plugin. In short, Eclipse is wasting of time when I'm not even trying to do something difficult.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for : "`managing plugins in eclipse is a nightmare` " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979470/how-to-fully-remove-subversive-plugin

Comment: @Niklas So your project is not an eclipse project yet? What programming language is it?

Comment: Try to uninstall Subversive via Eclipse Marketplace:

From Eclipse menu open Help -> Eclipse Market Place...

Then search for subversive, click uninstall under Subversive - SVN Team Provider

Restart the Eclipse.

Comment: Thankyou. Now I understand how to uninstall it but it is not intuitive where it is. I'm now installing the subclipse plugin instead which has worked for me before.

Comment: The marketplace is not pushed enough to be known to new eclipse users. It is very sad, because it also contains most necessary repositories and you can search and install for plugins there. It came with one or two versions back, but most tutorials still refer to the old add repo url and install method.

Comment: And change the name of your post back to something that is not driven by your anger, but is more informative. In case somebody out there is having the same problem, s/he will find your question more easily and get the answer quickly.

Comment: I restarted and reinstalled, now it works. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Perfect, I am happy that it helped.